# Remove the whole time series for ids when conditions are not satisfied

Tags: stata

I have a dataset that looks as follows:

```
clear

input int rssdid str8 date int totloan_net float(roa capital_ratio)
1847 "19950331"   192  .0035331  .225592
1847 "19950630"   222  .0079163 .2162655
1847 "19950930"   183  .0107548 .2282461
1847 "19951231"   220  .0127076 .1999296
1847 "19960331"   201  .0024221 .2397155
1847 "19960630"   176  .0034798 .2074997
1847 "19960930"   143  .0080418 .1952108
1847 "19961231"   367 -.0006507 .2247832
1847 "19970331"   465  .0014151 .2141977
1847 "19970630"   562  .0021164 .2248743
1847 "19970930"   896  .0006957 .2110587
1847 "19971231"  3929 -.0003643 .1433968
1847 "19980331"  4794 -.0007035 .1079151
3458 "19950331"  9842  .0024375 .0768022
3458 "19950630" 11175  .0012293 .0795287
3458 "19950930" 11451  .0043123 .0785296
3458 "19951231" 11035  .0025692 .0823405
3458 "19960331" 10414  .0032018 .0835595
end
```

Each unique `rssdid` represents a unique bank.

How can I use Stata to delete the whole time series for banks with their `capital_ratio` lower than `0.045` at least once in their history?

Comment: Note that your dates are as yet unfit for any serious Stata purpose. You have monthly data that happen to be given by the last day in each month. Read `help datetime` and use `mofd(daily())` to produce a new monthly date variable.

Comment: See https://www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=dm0042 for a detailed argument of why _distinct_ is a better word than _unique_ in this context.

Comment: Please always include data as code using the `dataex` command. Type `help dataex` for more details and full syntax. You can also find more information about how to ask reproducible questions on here in the [Stata tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/stata/info).

Answer (score 1):

One statement is enough:

```
bysort rssdid (capital_ratio) : drop if capital_ratio[1] < 0.045
```

Answer (score 0):

If you provide example data, it would be easier for others to find a solution. You may want to try this:

```
egen minratio = min(capital_ratio), by(RSSDID) 
drop if minratio < 0.045
```